# How can I hook up several buttons to a Raspberry Pi (or other device) and have a certain word appear on a screen for a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, linux, arduino

Some background info:
I do a Christmas Light show, one where it blinks to the music. This year I am going to be having a "jukebox" where a guest can press a button, and then the song will play. There will be 13 buttons individually hooked up to a device called an "Input pup." That is a piece of hardware from the company that makes the Christmas light controllers.

My question: On these buttons, I want to also have a wire going to a raspberry pi or arduino, something of that sort. When you press the button It would display on a screen "The current song is **SONG NAME** The Upcoming song is **SONG NAME**"

If there is no song in line, it could read something like "The Current Song is *SONG NAME.* There is no song selected to play next.

How can I accomplish this? This is what I think I know so far. I will need a raspberry pi, and something to connect the 13 buttons to the pi with. The pi will need to be running a script that tells it when button 1 is pressed, display the corresponding song. and somewhere in the script, it will need to act like a que, so if someone pressing 4 buttons, on the screen it will show all 4 songs are in line to be played next.

I want to be very clear that this WILL NOT BE actually controlling the lights, music, or even sending a signal for it to be played. This is for display purposes only so guests know what songs are in que.

One final thought; I guess the code will need to include the timing of the song, otherwise, how will it know that it's time to display the next song in line. So I guess it should be something like, when button one is pressed (providing there is a current song already playing), display the words "The next song is **Carol of the bells** for 200 seconds."

If there is no song currently playing (meaning no one pressed a button previously) AND there is no song to be played next, then the text should read something like "There are no songs selected. Please make your selection below."

Comment: This question is far too broad in scope. *Here's a detailed list of my requirements. Can someone explain to me exactly how I would do all of this stuff?* You may as well add *(Or better yet, just go ahead and write the code for me; I'll pick it up later. Thanks!)*, This site is for specific problems you're having with your code or a programmers tool, not a discussion about how to design or code your entire app. Do you have a **single, specific question** related to a **specific, limited scope** problem that we can help you with? I suggest the [tour] and [help] pages, especially [ask].

Comment: My apologies Ken. I'm only 16 years old, and was hoping someone could provide me with some guidance on this project. I do my light show to benefit the Make-A-Wish foundation, so it means a lot to me that this year is a success. I didn't mean to cause a problem.